# How do I create a custom format in Django for the following: YYYY-NNNN, where YYYY represents the year and NNNN represents a 4 digit numeric value

Tags: django, django-models, format

I been trying to find ways to create a custom format for a value input for a model. I can't seem to find the adequate way to create a a year then 4 digit number after the slash.

I would really appreciate if you could help.

Comment: do you have some input to start from? your question doesn't explain what you want to do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.